# Python raw_input fails for pipe

Tags: python, pipe

How do I capture piped text in python. For example something like this

```
cat foo.py | ./foo.py
```

in foo.py I have the following:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
  text = raw_input()
```

The problem is `raw_input()` terminates after the new line. How do I capture the whole thing as a string/list?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`raw_input` is just a helper for prompting the user interactively.  If you want to read any amount from stdin, use `sys.stdin.read()`.